# Drive.Files insert and copy are failing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to copy files using the Google Drive API in a Google Apps Script web app, ideally using the `Drive.Files.copy()` method.  I've also tried `Drive.Files.insert()` with no success.

I'm not an expert programmer and my guess is that I'm missing something basic in terms of how to structure the request.  Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
Drive.Files.copy(folders.items[i].id,
    {
        "parents": [
            {
                "id": properties.destId
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

Error: Parse Error

```
Drive.Files.copy({
    "fileId": folders.items[i].id,
    "request": {
        "parents": [
            {
                "id": properties.destId
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Error: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 2-3 only

```
Drive.Files.copy({
    "params": {
        "fileId": folders.items[i].id
    },
    "body": {
        "title": folders.items[i].title,
        "parents": [
            {
                "id": properties.destId
            }
        ],
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    }
});
```

Error: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 2-3 only

```
Drive.Files.copy(folders.items[i].id, {
    "title": folders.items[i].title,
    "parents": [
        {
            "kind": "drive#fileLink",
            "id": properties.destId
        }
    ],
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
});
```

Error: Parse Error

```
Drive.Files.insert({
    "title": folders.items[i].title,
    "parents": [
        {
            "kind": "drive#fileLink",
            "id": properties.destId
        }
    ],
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
});
```

Works, but I'd prefer to use `.copy` since I'm just trying to copy the folder and its easier than manually transferring all properties

Any help would be appreciated in how to structure this copy request.

### Edit

I realized that folders are not copy-able, wish might be causing some of these errors. However, the errors seem related to the way the request is structured, rather than because of an incompatible file, so I would still appreciate guidance on how to structure this request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just reversed the request body and parameters.  Here's the correct syntax:

```
Drive.Files.copy({
    "title": FILE_NAME,
    "parents": [
        {
            "kind": "drive#fileLink",
            "id": PARENT_ID
        }
    ],
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
},
FILE_ID
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual method for copying files in `Google apps script` is `makeCopy` method. It is smooth and less cumbersome.

The snippet might go like this:

```
while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
  }
```

For copying a particular folder based on you may make use of the following script.

```
function start() {

   //your search params go here
   var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders('modifiedDate > "2016-02-10" and "email@email.com" in owners'); 

   while (folders.hasNext()) {


   var sourceFolder = folders.next();
   var targetFolder = 'Copy of ' + sourceFolder;
   //Logger.log(sourceFolder);
  // Logger.log(targetFolder);


  var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder);
  var target = DriveApp.createFolder(targetFolder);

  if (source.hasNext()) {
    copyFolder(source.next(), target);
  }

 }
}


function copyFolder(source, target) {

  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files   = source.getFiles();

  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
  }

  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
  }  

}
```

Please let us know what exactly are you trying to accomplish, then we can try to be more precise.

Comment: Hello, yes I'm familiar with the methods you outlined. My app is using direct API calls to avoid some quirks of continuationTokens in FolderIterators and FileIterators. In order to reduce the number of api calls, I would like to make a copy using the id and metadata that I'll already have, instead of creating a File instance first.

Comment: Oh, you are familiar with this. As folders are not copy-able, I was trying to find a work around and finally managed to got the script working for copying folders in the above fashion. Hope someone else can help you with Direct API calls. Good luck! :)